# socket.io .authorization error on live server but not in localhost

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am new to node js and socket.io. i am implementing chat module on my website using node js and socket.io. I have successfully implement it on my localhost and it's working fine but after uploading files on the live server it doesn't work.
The error i am getting while running app.js file on server-

**var chatpage=io.of('/chatpage').authorization(function (handshakeData, callbac
                                ^
TypeError: Object # has no method 'authorization'**

here is my app.js file code-

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var socket = require('socket.io');
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = socket.listen(server);
var async = require('async');
var mysql= require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  host      : 'localhost',          
  user      : 'root',   
  password  : 'admin',
  database  : 'mychat'
});
var chatserver=require('./chatserver.js');
var chatpage=io.of('/chatpage').authorization(function (handshakeData, callback) {
  console.dir(handshakeData);
  handshakeData.page = 'chatpage';
  callback(null, true);
}).on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.dir(socket.handshake.page);
  chatserver.getUserFeeds(chatpage,socket,io,pool,async);
});
```

and connection on client page -

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
        var chatpage=socket.of('/chatpage')
            .on('connect_failed', function (reason) {
                console.error('unable to connect chatpage to namespace', reason);
            })
            .on('error',function(reason){
                console.error('unable to connect chatpage to namespace', reason);
            })
            .on('reconnect_failed',function(){
            })
            .on('connect', function () {
                console.info('sucessfully established a connection of chatpage with the namespace');
                chatpage.emit('senddata',{user_id:user_id,room_id:room_id});
            });
```

Please help me out where i am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you verify the socket.io versions are identical on local and server machines?

Comment: Hi alandarev, yes versions are identical on both the server(local and live).